# Pandas: select rows by random groups while keeping all of the group's variables

Tags: python, pandas, random, pandas-groupby, rows

My dataframe looks like this:

```
id  std     number 
A   1       1
A   0       12
B   123.45  34
B   1       56 
B   12      78
C   134     90
C   1234    100
C   12345   111
```

I'd like to select **random rows of Id** while retaining all of the information in the other rows, such that dataframe would look like this:

```
id  std     number 
A   1       1
A   0       12
C   134     90
C   1234    100
C   12345   111
```

I tried it with

```
size = 1000   
replace = True  
fn = lambda obj: obj.loc[np.random.choice(obj.index, size, replace),:]
df2 = df1.groupby('Id', as_index=False).apply(fn)
```

and

```
df2 = df1.sample(n=1000).groupby('id')
```

but obviously that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create random `id`s first and then compare original column `id` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#number of groups
N = 2
df2 = df1[df1['id'].isin(df1['id'].drop_duplicates().sample(N))]
print (df2)
  id      std  number
0  A      1.0       1
1  A      0.0      12
5  C    134.0      90
6  C   1234.0     100
7  C  12345.0     111
```

Or:

```
N = 2
df2 = df1[df1['id'].isin(np.random.choice(df1['id'].unique(), N))]
```